# How do you differentiate between the end of file and an error using fscanf() in C?

Tags: c, scanf, eof, feof

According to manual, `int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure. How shall I differentiate between:

- zero matched and assigned items
- end of the file
- an empty file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the 'return values' section of the POSIX specification for [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), for example.

- Zero matched and assigned items is reported by `fscanf()` returning 0.
- End of file is reported by `fscanf()` returning EOF.
- An empty file is reported by the first call to `fscanf()` returning EOF.

Note that the prescription makes it difficult to spot the difference between an empty file (no bytes) and a file with no useful data in it.  Consider this test program (I called it `eof59.c`, compiled to create `eof59`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    int rc;

    while ((rc = scanf("%255s", buffer)) != EOF)
        printf("%d: %s\n", rc, buffer);
}
```

If you run it with `/dev/null` as input (the ultimate empty file), it says nothing.  However, it also says nothing if you feed it a file with a single blank (and no newline), or just a newline, or indeed any sequence of white space.  You can also experiment replace the format string with `" x %255s"`.  Feeding it a file with just an `x` (possibly with white space around it) generates no output.  Feed it a file with a `y` as the first character (other than white space) and the program runs for a long time reporting `0:` on each line of output.

Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/151680), but after a function such as `scanf()` has returned EOF, you can legitimately use `feof()` and `ferror()` to disambiguate between genuine EOF and an error on the file stream (such as a disk crashing or …).

```
if (feof(stdin))
    printf("EOF on standard input\n");
if (ferror(stdin))
    printf("Error on standard input\n");
```

With the code shown, you should normally see 'EOF on standard input'; it would probably be quite hard to generate (even simulate) an error on standard input.  You should not see both messages, and you should always see one of the messages.

Comment: Ok, so if `fscanf()` returns 0, it failed to assign the items or the file is empty and if it returns `EOF`, the file is empty or it's at the end, right?

Comment: If the file is empty - nothing could be read - EOF would be returned

Comment: you could add about the *correct use* of `feof` and `ferror` here :D

Comment: @tomashauser — basically, that's correct.  You get EOF when `fscanf()` encounters EOF and had done nothing except skip white space or other literal characters in the format string.  You get 0 if there was some data left but the format string (e.g. `"x %s"` in the code in my updated answer) didn't match the input.

Comment: "runs for a ling time" is an understatement.